# What's the story from 365tomorrows about the "chain of command" taken to its extreme?

Tags: story-identification

I *know* I read this on [365tomorrows](http://365tomorrows.com), but I have not been able to find it again.

It's a story (spoilers...) about a lowly guy (janitor maybe?) on a spaceship, where the onboard computer wakes him up, pumps him full of drugs, and guides him towards the bridge to take over the captain's chair...

> ...because *everybody else* has died. The ship is obviously no longer capable of sustaining life, and the computer is just mindlessly working its way down the entire roster.

Comment: Can you remember any *specific* words that were used in the story? If so, you can do a very quick url search on google; (***inurl:http://365tomorrows.com/ "roster"***)

Comment: Closest I've found so far is "We Love Bunnies" where the fellow was 10 from the bottom and the main thrust of the narrative is that the aliens really like Earth bunnies.

Comment: I wish, @Valorum! I've tried dang near everything, and I do know my way around Google. What I need is another _brain_ that can answer your question, and mine.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, definitely wrong, I'm afraid. There were (I think?) no aliens, and _certainly_ no bunnies! Just the ship and its crew.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it could be ["Sick Leave"](http://365tomorrows.com/2008/03/08/sick-leave/) by V.L.Ilian

Low level shipmember woken and promoted to captain:

> “You’ve been exposed to lethal doses of radiation. You must make your way to the auxiliary bridge”
>
> “WHY? Where’s the captain?”
>
> “You are acting captain”
>
> “I’m a level 2 tech!”

Pumped full of drugs:

> “You pumped me full of damn stims to wake me up? That’s why I’m bleeding from every pore."

Learns she's the highest ranking officer:

> “This doesn’t make sense… the succession order goes by rank there are hundreds of people above me and… everybody’s dead.”
>
> “Linda Kroen 155013 is the highest ranking living crewmember. You must proceed to the auxiliary bridge to enable the main cannon.”

Comment: That certainly matches the description.

Comment: It certainly does! Thanks, @starpilotsix! (great user name, by the way)